# Magick++.h header not found

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to get g++ to compile a program that uses Magick++, however despite installing the libraries, I get the below error when compiling the program with `` g++ WallFade.cpp `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs` -o WallFade ``:

```
fatal error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <Magick++.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

When I set an absolute path to the header file by replacing `#include <Magick++.h>` with `#include "/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++.h"` I then get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: line 47: --cflags: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: line 50: --cflags: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: line 53: --libs: command not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: line 56: --libs: command not found
In file included from WallFade.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++.h:10:10: fatal error: Magick++/Include.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include <Magick++/Include.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm assuming I need to run some command to link the header files to g++, but I'm not sure what that command would be (currently running Arch Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Install following package `libmagick++-dev`

```
packman -S libmagick++-dev
```

I think this is the way to install it on Arch.

Comment: I tried that, but I get `error: target not found: libmagick++-dev`